# Как правильно рассчитать путь?

Tags: javascript, php, карты

У меня есть приложение для такси. Стал вопрос, что бы цена рассчитывалась с учетом того, вызывается такси в городе или за город. Эту задачу еще кое-как я смогу решить, но надо еще считать сколько метров в городе и сколько метров за городом, так как это разные тарифы.

Вопрос: возможно ли вообще такое и если да, то с помощью каких средств?

Приложение использует js, серверная версия на php

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

P.S. Удалось добиться, что бы возвращались шаги маршрута, прикладываю пример

```
0: {intersections: [{out: 0, entry: [true], bearings: [23], location: [25.332172, 50.755208]}],…}
distance: 34.6
driving_side: "right"
duration: 13.8
geometry: "acxtHauryCSMOv@"
intersections: [{out: 0, entry: [true], bearings: [23], location: [25.332172, 50.755208]}]
maneuver: {bearing_after: 23, type: "depart", modifier: "right", bearing_before: 0,…}
mode: "driving"
name: ""
weight: 22.2

1: {intersections: [,…], driving_side: "right", geometry: "edxtHwsryCfAn@~AfAn@\VNHFTVx@`@",…}
distance: 201.2
driving_side: "right"
duration: 18.1
geometry: "edxtHwsryCfAn@~AfAn@\VNHFTVx@`@"
intersections: [,…]
maneuver: {bearing_after: 201, type: "turn", modifier: "left", bearing_before: 292,…}
mode: "driving"
name: "Стрілецька вулиця"
weight: 18.1
```

Пока не могу понять, куда смотреть дальше

Comment: Для этого есть открытые источники типа Openstreetmap, где можно проверить в каком полигоне/координатах находится та или иная точка, и на основе этого делать свои вычисления. Тем более если разговор идёт только об одном городе, достать полигон geojson не составит проблемы. Смотрите проект Nominatim и OSM.

Comment: я как раз использую osm. для построения маршрута использую http://project-osrm.org/. сейчас добился, что бы кроме основных данных возвращались еще шаги маршрута. но вот куда дальше двигаться - не пойму. в описание выложу пример шагов

Comment: Смотрите в сторону https://map.project-osrm.org/, там есть всё для построения пути, получения дистанций и тд. с использованием проекта OSRM.

Comment: построить путь я могу, он у меня строится. вопрос в том, как понять, какая часть входит в границы города, а какая нет

Comment: У вас путь имеет точки (координаты), вы же можете их использовать на проверку город/не-город и рассчитать примерную дистанцию, разве нет? Для более высокой точности можете расссчитать пересечение прямой пути с полигоном для получения точной точки выезда из/в город.